# Should questions on Specific songs be allowed?

Tags: discussion

I've been thinking a lot about this since the [Oasis question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/11285/oasis-supersonic-harmonic-analysis-what-modes-are-played-explaining-modulati)

I'm inclined to say yes, but a user on the question believes that we should be asking about specific sections, specific techniques or theoretical points.

I have a vast array of questions about sections of music by Bach, Dream Theater and Frank Zappa which have entire [sites](http://www.zappa-analysis.com/) dedicated to them, potentially opening up waaaaaay to big a can of worms.  There's also the belief as in StackOverflow that questions must show a basic understanding, and that research has been done on the question beforehand, and in the Oasis question it seems like the user has some idea about modes and key signatures, albeit a little flawed.

On the other hand, a song can have a great many things going on harmonically.  you could write a thesis on a 2 minute Bach invention.  My guess is that it has to be about what specific element the user is asking about, otherwise the scope is too general.

But then again, I could start every answer with "Well, you have these waveforms called fundamental harmonics..."

Comment: I'm OK with the general area that question falls into, less so with the actual question.  It just doesn't make a lot of sense and is pretty discussiony.

Comment: I believe that's the purpose of Meta, to clarify issues and discuss the philosophy behind questions/answers.  What doesn't make sense about the question?

Comment: I was referring to the question you've linked.  I've changed "this" to "that" in my original comment, hopefully it's clearer.

Comment: aaah, I see.  I agree that it is badly worded, but it does bring up the issue of if it's a valid question.  should it be more specific, less focused on the one song?